# Contents of parent folder not visible on the website

Tags: network

I was surfing through this website `http://example.com/admin1/`. If you open `admin1` folder, nothing is shown but if you open this `http://example.com/admin1/Serial/Person.of.Interest/` then the contents are shown.

How is this happening that contents of the parent folder are not shown but that of sub-folder i.e. `Serial/Person.of.Interest` are?

Is this some kind of settings/options on web server or anything else?

Comment: A virtual index on a website only behaves like a directory structure on a computer to make things easier. While permissions on a filesystem ensure that you need all directories in a path to have sufficient permissions to enter to read any further subdirectory, there is nothing preventing a server from return 403 or even return nothing if the requested path doesn't match allowed paths.

Comment: You can do this with .htaccess

Comment: do not repost the same question when has been closed

Comment: and please redact URLs that provide copyright-infringing content

Comment: @divyanshu There is no SE site for this question. It requires that you first understand the basics of "permissions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the path of the URL does not need to reflect an actual path in the file system at all. It is just an identifier of a resource and it is up to the web server or web application how this identifier is mapped to a resource. For example with more complex sites you have usually some application logic which extracts parts from the identifier and then dynamically generates the result based on results for database lookups for these parts.

But even if the path in the URL does reflect an actual path on the file system today's web servers have ways to restrict access to some path while still allowing access to other path which are inside the restricted path. See for example [Apache - How to deny directory but allow one file in that dirctory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243677/apache-how-to-deny-directory-but-allow-one-file-in-that-dirctory) or [Apache - Deny listing directory but allow access to all subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840323/apache-deny-listing-directory-but-allow-access-to-all-subfolders) for the details on how to do this.